# Doubt regarding straddled lemma.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, derivatives

There was a problem in real analysis which states that if $f$ has a derivative at $x_0$ and $f$ is defined on $(a,b)$,then for any two sequence $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ satisfying $\alpha_n \to 0 , \beta_n\to 0$ and $\alpha_n<x_0<\beta_n$,we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(\alpha_n)-f(\beta_n)}{\alpha_n-\beta_n}=f'(x_0)$,but the converse is not true for example $f(x)=|x|$  on $(-1,1)$.
But In Elementary Real Analysis by Bruckener Thomson,I found that an equivalent formulation of derivative which is through the straddled criterion that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if $\lim_{u \to x+,v \to x-}\frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u}$ exists and is equal to $f'(x)$.How can it be ,doesn't it fail for $|x|$?

Comment: No it doesn't fail for $|x|$. That limit does not exist for $x=0$, and $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Is this same as the sequential version I wrote?

Comment: I would need to see how you are phrasing the converse, but it does look like $|x|$ is not a counterexample to either version of the statement.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Converse means if for each pair of sequences $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n $satisfying the two conditions(i.e. they tend to $x_0$ one from each direction of $x_0$,the limit of the quotient as $n\to \infty$ is a particular real number $l$,then $f$ has a derivative at that point.and $f'(x_0)=l$.

Comment: That premise clearly does not apply to $|x|$ at 0

Comment: @MorganRodgers does not apply means?

Comment: I don't believe it is true that every such pair of sequences will give you that limit approaching some fixed real number $l$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes of course you are right,got it.

Comment: @MorganRodgers So the sequential criteria and straddled lemma are equivalent right?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. Obviously the continuous version implies the discrete version. To show the other way, assume the continuous limit does not converge to a value $l$. Then for each $n$, pick values of $u,v$ such that the quotient differs from $l$ by at least $1/n$. These form sequences that do not converge to $l$ either. If for every $l$, the continuous limit does not converge to it, then there is at least one pair of sequences that do not converge to it either. Thus the sequential condition is also false.